# Registered container instances 0 AWS ECS

Tags: amazon-web-services, cluster-computing, amazon-ecs

I created a cluster on Amazon ECS. It was successful but my Registered container instances is zero. I can't create a tasks because my cluster doesn't a container have an instance.

What to do? Hope you can help me. Thank you.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You don't have any instances in your cluster? Can you check if any EC2 is running?

Comment: @AshBlake Yes there is an instance running in my EC2 that's why I'm not sure what the problem is. What might be the possible issue here ?

Comment: Hmm, if there is an EC2, can you check in the ECS console if EC2 joined the cluster successfully or not?

Comment: No, in my ECS instances tab I can't find any container instance pertaining to the EC2. @AshBlake

Comment: Hmm, if in your ECS console does not have any in ECS instances tab, you can try to update cluster to add 1 instance

Comment: What is  the user data of your instance?

Answer (score 0):

EC2 instances won't be visible out of the box in the ECS cluster just because they exist in your account. They need to be made join the cluster. First you'd need to use an ECS-optimized AMI (unless you want to build one on your own which is possible but..) and then you'd need to customize the launch to tell it which cluster to join. See [this doc page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/bootstrap_container_instance.html).

You have 3 options:

- re-launch one (or more) new EC2 instances following the doc above
- re provision a cluster using the wizard and select that you want to deploy EC2 instances as well (this wizard will just to everything for you). Since you have an empty cluster you probably selected to deploy a cluster with no instances in the wizard
- [ best ] re-launch your task using the Fargate launch type. Fargate is an AWS managed engine that allows you to launch containers/tasks without having customer provisioned infrastructure (i.e. EC2 instances).